# Python pivot DataFrame without index columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

It is intrducing nulls in resultant dataframe 
df.pivot( columns='colname',values='value')

Initial DF:

```
    colname    value
0   bathrooms   1.0
1   bathrooms   2.0
2   bathrooms   1.0
3   bathrooms   2.0
4   property_id 82671.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckYHD.png)
Result:

```
colname   addr_street   bathrooms   bedrooms    lat lng parking_space   property_id
0           NaN            1.0        NaN       NaN NaN NaN              NaN
1           NaN            2.0        NaN       NaN NaN NaN              NaN
2           NaN            1.0        NaN       NaN NaN NaN              NaN
```

I just want a dataframe where unique values of 'colname' in initial df are the columns and the its corresponding value is the value(like it happens in bathroom)

Comment: Please post your code rather than a picture of your code

Comment: Please don't deface your questions or it's answers with destructive edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want a `groupby` and `concat`enation, not pivot:

```
df = pd.concat(
        {k: g.reset_index(drop=True) 
            for k, g in df.groupby('colname')['value']}, axis=1)
```

```
df
   bathrooms  property_id
0        1.0      82671.0
1        2.0          NaN
2        1.0          NaN
3        2.0          NaN
```